# Selenium: How to parse through a code after using selenium to click a dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape trough this webpage https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/. Up to now I have achieved for the code to use the requests method to use the search bar. After that, I want to look for the different prices of the compounds. The html code that includes the prices is not visible until the Price dropdown has been clicked. I have achieved that by using selenium to click all the dropdowns with the desired class. But after that, I do not know how to get the html code of the webpage that is generated after clicking the dropdowns and where the price is placed.

Here's my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

#get the desired search terms by imput

 name=input("Reagent: ")
 CAS=input("CAS: ")

  #search using the name of the compound

  data_name= {'term':name, 'interface':'Product%20Name', 'N':'0+',
       'mode':'mode%20matchpartialmax', 'lang':'es','region':'ES',
        'focus':'product', 'N':'0%20220003048%20219853286%20219853112'}
   #search using the CAS of the compound

   data_CAS={'term':CAS, 'interface':'CAS%20No.', 'N':'0','mode':'partialmax',
        'lang':'es', 'region':'ES', 'focus':'product'}
#get the link of the name search
 r=requests.post("https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/search/",    params=data_name.items())

 #get the link of the CAS search
n=requests.post("https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/search/",    params=data_CAS.items())

#use selenium to click in the dropdown(only for the name search)

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(r.url)
dropdown=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("expandArrow")
for arrow in dropdown:
    arrow.click()
```

As I said, after this I need to find a way to get the html code after opening the dropdowns so that I can look for the price class. I have tried different things but I don't seem to get any working solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what _different things_ you have tried so far to extract the price? Show us your code snippet and html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You should use WebDriverWait as Austen had pointed out.

For your question try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(r.url)
dropdown=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("expandArrow")
for arrow in dropdown:
    arrow.click()
    html_source = driver.page_source
    print(html_source)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, this has worked, I have tried it using sleep instead of the WebDriverWait function because I don't really know how to use it yet (I'm currently looking into it) and I have gotten good results.

Comment:  I am glad to help! You really should use webdriverwait!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Selenium WebDriverWait. [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(css));
```

Comment: You are correct!! The best way to automate with selenium is using WebDriverWait yet his question was about how to get all of the HTML code... Hence my answer...